# Swift 4, passing UISwipeGestureRecognizer direction to the handler function

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, swipe

I have a view that has a swipe recognizer that sends it to the moveToNextItem function:

```
let swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(moveToNextItem))     
swipe.direction = [.left, .right]
playCardView.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)
```

Currently the moveToNextItem function just handles both left and right swipes the same:

```
@objc func moveToNextItem() {
    //Moves to next item
}
```

What is the right way to pass the direction that the user swiped to that function so it can move left or right. I could create 2 functions (one for left and one for right) but that seems like a bad way to do it. I'd like to just pass the direction to the function and let the function what should happen. Maybe in a way so the function could switch on the directions? Something like this:

```
@objc func moveToNextItem() {
        switch direction{
        case .left:
             //left swipe action
        case .right:
             //right swipe action
        default: //default
        }
    }
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to create the two separate  gesture for each swipe event,reason is actually works in single event,  for e.g

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(moveToNextItem(_:)))
let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(moveToNextItem(_:)))

leftSwipe.direction = .left
rightSwipe.direction = .right

playCardView.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
playCardView.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
}
```

> When a gesture is detected the moveToNextItem method is called, implement this method.

```
@objc func moveToNextItem(_ sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

   switch sender.direction{
    case .left:
         //left swipe action
    case .right:
         //right swipe action
    default: //default
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I just couldn't get the syntax right.

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of to methods

**First Method**

```
/// My Gesture For Multiple DIrection
private var mySwipeGesturec: UISwipeGestureRecognizer?

/// Directions Array
let directionsArray: [UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection] = [.right, .left]
/// Create For Loop
for currentDirection in directionsArray {
     mySwipeGesturec = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
     mySwipeGesturec = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onScreenCodes.swipeHandler(_:)))
     mySwipeGesturec?.direction = currentDirection
     self.view.addGestureRecognizer(mySwipeGesturec!)
}

@objc func swipeHandler(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        switch sender.direction {
        case .left:
            print("Left Swipe")
        case .right:
            print("Right Swipe")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

**Second Method**

```
private var leftSwipeGesture : UISwipeGestureRecognizer?
private var rightSwipeGesture : UISwipeGestureRecognizer?


leftSwipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
leftSwipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onScreenCodes.swipeHandler(_:)))
leftSwipeGesture?.direction = .left
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipeGesture!)

rightSwipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
rightSwipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onScreenCodes.swipeHandler(_:)))
rightSwipeGesture?.direction = .right
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipeGesture!)


@objc func swipeHandler(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        switch sender.direction {
        case .left:
            print("Left Swipe")
        case .right:
            print("Right Swipe")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

**Note** Both are same its just Depends on Your requirement